# How to use executemany() to insert multiple rows but ignore the erroneous ones?

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, insert

I am using Python MySQLdb to insert data into a mysql database.

`InsertList` contains many rows. All are valid except for a few which violate database integrity rules. 
If I run the code below, the command returns an error.

Cursor1.executemany(query, InsertList)

How can I force executemany() to insert the rows which are valid but ignore the few which are erroneous? The erroneous ones are caused by duplicate values in the new row. Do I have to use execute() one by one to insert the rows instead?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the SQL command

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO
```

instead of plain

```
INSERT INTO
```

Here is a [reference to the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html). Note that there is also `INSERT REPLACE` (to replace duplicates with the new values) and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` for more control.